# Why is my function not working correctly in C

Tags: c, function, struct

This is a section of a problem I'm working on. The leap year part is not returning correctly. It returns 29 for February whether I put in a leap year or not. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

struct date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;
};

int main (void)
{
    struct date now;
    void numberOfDays (struct date v);
    bool findLeap (struct date v);
    printf("Enter the date in this format mm/dd/yyyy: ");
    scanf("%i", &now.month, &now.day, &now.year);

    numberOfDays(now);

    return 0;
}

void numberOfDays (struct date v)
{
    int daysOfMonth;
    bool findLeap (struct date v);

    if (v.month == 4 || v.month == 6 || v.month == 9 || v.month == 11)
        daysOfMonth = 30;

    else if (v.month == 2)
    {
        findLeap(v);
        if (findLeap)
            daysOfMonth = 29;
        else
            daysOfMonth = 28;
    }

    else
        daysOfMonth = 31;

    printf("Number of days in month: %i", daysOfMonth);
}


bool findLeap (struct date v)
{
    bool isLeap;

    if ( v.year % 4 == 0 && v.year % 100 != 0 || v.year % 400 == 0)
    {
        isLeap = true;
    }
    else
    {
        isLeap = false;
    }

    return isLeap;
}
```

Comment: You `scanf` is wrong - three values but only one in the format string. `scanf("%i", ...` -> `scanf("%i %i %i", ...`

Comment: Yes, I had it correct earlier but in the midst of trying everything I didn't change it back. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
findLeap(v);
if (findLeap)
```

The above doesn't branch on the return value of `findLeap`, it's always true. It's like that, because function identifiers implicitly convert to function pointers, and when checked against in a conditional, will just evaluate to true.

So just write it correctly:

```
if (findLeap(v))
```

---

Oh, and might I suggest a better name? Since the functions purpose is to answer a query, I think it should have a name that reads like one. I'd go for `isLeapYear`.

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I'll try it out. Really appreciate the help!